# Can't determine what parameters to pass to a OSM2PO SOAP call

Tags: osm2po, soap

I've been experimenting with OSM2PO which is a great little peace of software.  Right now though, I'm fumbling with the SOAP WS which I'm trying to use from a JEE web application.  I'm not having any trouble to setup the call to the webservice and can call upon one of the two webmethods described in the WSDL : findClosestVertexId() and findRoute().  Finding a close-by vertex ID from coordinates is no trouble at all but calling findRoute() is somewhat puzzling me as it takes four parameters : the two start and end points of the route and - RouterID (integer) and parameters (String).  My question is : what do I put in those last two?  I'm asking because actually I'm not getting anything from findRoute().  I've been trying something like 
`findRoute(myStartVertexID,myEndVertexId,1,"") but the List<RoutingResultSegment> I get is desperatly empty (getLength() returns 0!)`.  I'm guessing this is because I'm misusing the findRoute() method and not putting proper parameters in the method call.

Anybody experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot.  The few lines in the given example, below the comment "// graph: lazy, cached, auto closed", are a relief (never been at ease in dealing with files...too many bad memories)!

Agreed then, I'll try using Osm2po as a lib instead of going with the SOAP service.

Answer (score 0):

```
public RoutingResult findRoute (
        @WebParam(name="sourceId") int sourceId,
        @WebParam(name="targetId") int targetId, 
        @WebParam(name="routerId") Integer routerId,
        @WebParam(name="params") String args) {
```

1. sourceId: Id of Source-Vertex
2. targetId: Id of Target-Vertex
3. routerId: Optional - Id of Router-Implementation (Have a look into
   the osm2po.config. 0 is the DefaultRouter)
4. args: Optional - Komma-separated list of additional string-args for the Router-Implementation. e.g. "findShortestPath=true,ignoreRestrictions=false"

On a lighter note: Why do you use the SOAP-Interface anyway? It's easier to utilize osm2po directly - as Java-Lib.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carsten, it does clear things up a bit.  However I must say that "routerID" and "params" are not optional - not at least with the auto-generated code from netbeans based on the WSDL.  Since I'm not your everyday SOAP Guru, I might be missing a thing or two and I only use SOAP with tons of automated stuff in netbeans.  Anyways, everything works fine now.

I wanted to try the SOAP interface because I don't feel so comfortable with having to open and close the graph file myself - I dread concurrent access problems to the graph file...I figured you'd have prepared something nice on the SOAP code side of things, without having me to worry about it.  But you are right I guess, it's probably better to use it as a lib and besides, it can then be used in a servlet container or JEE compliant server.

Then again, if I use it in a web-app, I'll be delivering a routing service through SOAP and/or REST WS, so maybe that's another reason I went for the SOAP interface - already done (and I do tend to be lazy at times...).

Anyways, thanks for your quick answer which helped a lot, and thanks for Osm2Po!

Comment: It depends on the generator framework. ADB e.g. is not able to transport Integer.NULLs. Here you must use Integer.MINVALUE instead. With JaxWS or JAXB it is possible. In SOAP-UI you can delete both parameters - you can even delete the entire tag-line.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea how a servlet might look like:

[osm2po in a servlet container](http://gitorious.org/~fb71/polymap3/falkos-polymap-atlas/blobs/devel-routing/plugins/org.polymap.routing/src/org/polymap/routing/osm2po/Osm2poServlet.java)